# App crashes when it tries to access database

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm trying to create a simple login/register system using `TinyWebDB`.

However when I try to use my app to login or register an account it will instantly quit with no error message.

I'm guessing it has something to do with that database as the other functions that don't use the database works fine I've attached the designer and blocks for the registration page (login is pretty much the same), some ideas on what may be causing this would be very appreciated.

[Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq7Yz.png)
[image]

[Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUIdN.png)

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: I don't know of any error logs for App Inventor but there is a spot for warnings / errors in codes however they both show 0

Comment: just a small tip: never use the `open another screen` block together with 'Screen1', Why? see here 
[The recommended method of switching screens in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

Comment: [Why shouldn't I store passwords in plaintext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext) Store a hash value instead, my [tools extension](https://puravidaapps.com/tools.php) can help you with a hash method: *HmacSha256*...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure there is a spot in your code that confirms a connection to the database. That should throw an error if you cannot connect to the data. Also, make sure all permissions are set up properly such that the proper instructions have access to read the database.

Comment: I just added a code to detect errors in connecting to the database however the app closes the moment i hit register so i cant tell whether it was having connection problems or not. As for the code, Blocks = Code for App Inventor

Comment: nevermind, apparently initializing in the design section doesn't do anything and i have to initialize it in the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the app crashing and TinyWebDB. App Inventor is extremely finicky when it comes to urls. If you are using a custom tiny web database, make sure that your service url looks exactly like this:

```
http://your_database_name_here.appspot.com/
```

If you aren't using a custom one, make sure that you didn't accidentally change the url from the default.